# Longest Increasing Path in a Matrix Time Complexity Analysis

Tags: ruby, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

I'm working on the algorithm below:

```
Given an integer matrix, find the length of the longest increasing path.

From each cell, you can either move to four directions: left, right, up or down. You may NOT move diagonally or move outside of the boundary (i.e. wrap-around is not allowed).

Example 1:

nums = [
  [9,9,4],
  [6,6,8],
  [2,1,1]
]
Return 4
The longest increasing path is [1, 2, 6, 9].

Example 2:

nums = [
  [3,4,5],
  [3,2,6],
  [2,2,1]
]
Return 4
The longest increasing path is [3, 4, 5, 6]. Moving diagonally is not allowed.
```

My initial impulse was to have 4 functions in each direction that has an increasing value. For example, if integer 1 is in [1,1], and the four values surrounding that cell are increasing, then three functions will be created. This process, for every cell in worst case, I believe is O(4^(M*N) [4 function calls per each element, and there are mxn elements].

However, the solutions suggest the following brute force (before they go on to optimize it with memoization):

```
Algorithm

Each cell can be seen as a vertex in a graph G. If two adjacent cells have value a < ba<b, i.e. increasing then we have a directed edge (a, b)(a,b). The problem then becomes:

Search the longest path in the directed graph G.
Naively, we can use DFS or BFS to visit all the cells connected starting from a root. We update the maximum length of the path during search and find the answer when it finished.

Usually, in DFS or BFS, we can employ a set visited to prevent the cells from duplicate visits. We will introduce a better algorithm based on this in the next section.

Java

// Naive DFS Solution
// Time Limit Exceeded
public class Solution {
  private static final int[][] dirs = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}};
  private int m, n;

  public int longestIncreasingPath(int[][] matrix) {
      if (matrix.length == 0) return 0;
      m = matrix.length;
      n = matrix[0].length;
      int ans = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
          for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
              ans = Math.max(ans, dfs(matrix, i, j));
      return ans;
  }

  private int dfs(int[][] matrix, int i, int j) {
      int ans = 0;
      for (int[] d : dirs) {
          int x = i + d[0], y = j + d[1];
          if (0 <= x && x < m && 0 <= y && y < n && matrix[x][y] > matrix[i][j])
              ans = Math.max(ans, dfs(matrix, x, y));
      }
      return ++ans;
  }
}
```

The time complexity for this algorithm which is pretty similar (just launches 4 dfs functions in the worst case for a single cell) has the following complexity analysis:

```
Complexity Analysis

Time complexity : O(2^{m+n))
​​ ). The search is repeated for each valid increasing path. In the worst case we can have O(2^{m+n)) calls. For example:
1 2 3 . . . n
2 3 . . .   n+1
3 . . .     n+2
.           .
.           .
.           .
m m+1 . . . n+m-1
Space complexity : O(mn). For each DFS we need O(h) space used by the system stack, where hh is the maximum depth of the recursion. In the worst case, O(h) =O(mn).
```

I'm not following how they got this time complexity or the space complexity. For space cost, I imagine the worst case scenario is a matrix which is sorted in ascending order in rows and cols,  but a single stack will be roughly proportional to the diagonal length of the mxn square. Is that why the space is worst case proportional to O(mn)? Also, how is the space cost O(2^(m+n)) and not O(4^(m*n)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Sunny is correct that brute force searches have a time complexity of O(`4^(m*n)`), where `n` and `m` are the numbers of rows and columns in the matrix associated with the given array. I would like to suggest a O(`n*m`) algorithm and Ruby code that implements it .

In problems such as this one, the tendency is to consider moving from each element in a matrix to all adjacent larger-valued elements (up to 4), and then from each of those elements to all of their adjacent larger-valued elements, and so on (hence O(`4^m*n`)). Because the paths must be increasing, however, we can view the problem in a different way that permits us to develop a highly-efficient optimization algorithm.

Suppose we group all the locations by value. For the example given in the question, this might be expressed:

```
value_to_locs
  #=> { 9=>[[0, 0], [0, 1]], 4=>[[0, 2]], 6=>[[1, 0], [1, 1]], 8=>[[1, 2]],
  #     2=>[[2, 0]], 1=>[[2, 1], [2, 2]]}
```

Next let's consider the values of the hash in decreasing order:

```
to_process = value_to_locs.keys.sort.reverse
  #=> [9, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1]
```

First we process the two locations with value `9`. The length of an increasing path from either of these locations is clearly `1` (the paths being `[[0, 0]]` and `[[1, 0]]`), as there's nowhere to go. We save this information to a previously-empty hash, `processed`, which is now:

```
processed = { [0, 0]=>{ len: 1, next: nil }, [1, 1]=>{ len: 1, next: nil } }
```

Next consider the single location with value `8` (the second element of `to_process`), `[1, 2]`. If an increasing path from this location has a length greater than `1` it must next go to one of the elements of `processed`. `[1, 2]` is adjacent to neither to `[0, 0]` nor `[1, 1]`, so we add the key-value pair:

```
[1, 2]=>{ len: 1, next: nil }
```

to `processed`, obtaining

```
processed
  #=> { [0, 0]=>{ len: 1, next: nil }, [1, 1]=>{ len: 1, next: nil },
  #     [1, 2]=>{ len: 1, next: nil } }
```

The next value (in `to_process`) to examine is `6`, which occurs at two locations, `[1, 0]` and `[1, 1]`. The former is adjacent to one location in `processed` (`[0, 0]`), so we add to `processed` the key-value pair

```
[1, 0]=>{ len: 1 + processed[[0, 0]][:len], next: [0, 0] }
     #=>{ len: 2, next: [0, 0] }
```

The other element with value `6`, `[1, 1]` has two adjacent elements in `processed`, `[0, 1]` and `[1, 2]`, so add

```
[1, 1]=>{ len: 1 + processed[[0, 1]][:len], next: [0, 1] }
     #=>{ len: 2, next: [0, 1] }
```

or

```
[1, 1]=>{ len: 1 + processed[[1, 2]][:len], next: [1, 2] }
     #=>{ len: 2, next: [1, 2] }
```

to `processed`, namely, the one for which the value of `:len` is greatest. (Here, it's a tie, so either can be chosen.)

We continue this way until all the elements of the original array are keys in `processed`. We then select as the starting point of the longest increasing path the location `loc` for which `processed[loc][:len]` is greatest, and reconstruct the associated path.

Note the key `:next` is needed merely to reconstruct the longest path. If only the length of the longest path is needed, that key is not needed.

**Code**

```
def longest_increasing_path(arr)
  row_indices, col_indices = 0..arr.size-1, 0..arr.first.size-1
  value_to_locs = row_indices.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |r,h|
    col_indices.each { |c| h[arr[r][c]] << [r,c] } }
  processed = {}
  value_to_locs.keys.sort.reverse.each do |x|
    value_to_locs[x].each do |loc|
      next_on_path = greater_neighbors(loc, arr, row_indices, col_indices).
        max_by { |nloc| processed[nloc][:len] }
      processed[loc] = next_on_path ? 
          { len: 1+processed[next_on_path][:len], next: next_on_path } :
          { len: 1, next: nil }
    end
  end
  extract_path(processed)
end  

def longest_increasing_path(arr)
  row_indices, col_indices = 0..arr.size-1, 0..arr.first.size-1
  value_to_locs = row_indices.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |r,h|
    col_indices.each { |c| h[arr[r][c]] << [r,c] } }
  processed = {}
  low, high = value_to_locs.keys.minmax
  high.downto(low) do |x|
    next unless value_to_locs.key?(x)
    value_to_locs[x].each do |loc|
      next_on_path = greater_neighbors(loc, arr, row_indices, col_indices).
        max_by { |nloc| processed[nloc][:len] }
      processed[loc] = next_on_path ? 
          { len: 1+processed[next_on_path][:len], next: next_on_path } :
          { len: 1, next: nil }
    end
  end
  extract_path(processed)
end
```

```
def greater_neighbors((r,c), arr, row_indices, col_indices)
  curr_val = arr[r][c]
  [[-1,0], [1,0], [0,-1], [0, 1]].each_with_object([]) do |(rdelta, cdelta), a|
    ra = r + rdelta
    ca = c + cdelta
    a << [ra, ca] if row_indices.cover?(ra) && col_indices.cover?(ca) &&
      curr_val < arr[ra][ca]
  end
end

def extract_path(processed)
  loc, g = processed.max_by { |loc,g| g[:len] }
  len = g[:len]
  path = [loc]
  loop do
    break if g[:next].nil?
    loc = g[:next]
    path << loc        
    g = processed[loc]
  end
  [len, path]
end
```

**Examples**

**#1**

```
arr = [
  [9,9,4],
  [6,6,8],
  [2,1,1]
]

longest_increasing_path(arr)
  #=> [4, [[2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

**#2**

```
rows = 10
cols = 10
a = (1..9).to_a
arr = Array.new(rows) { Array.new(cols) { a.sample } }
  #=> [[4, 7, 5, 3, 5, 4, 2, 2, 9, 3],
  #    [8, 3, 3, 5, 4, 2, 8, 1, 8, 3],
  #    [7, 1, 9, 4, 2, 7, 1, 4, 4, 6],
  #    [3, 7, 5, 5, 2, 3, 9, 1, 9, 7],
  #    [2, 6, 7, 1, 5, 9, 3, 5, 2, 9],
  #    [4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 4, 9, 7, 6, 1],
  #    [9, 7, 5, 4, 6, 8, 8, 4, 4, 8],
  #    [3, 1, 9, 9, 5, 7, 9, 6, 7, 2],
  #    [5, 6, 4, 8, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 9],
  #    [7, 9, 6, 9, 5, 2, 9, 7, 6, 3]] 

require 'time'
t = Time.now
longest_increasing_path(arr)
  #=> [5, [[6, 3], [6, 2], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4]]] 
Time.now - t
  #=> 0.003606 seconds
```

The longest path is therefore of length `5` and contains the elements `4`, at `[6, 3]` then left to `5`, up to `6`, right to `7`, right to `8`.

**#3**

```
rows = 100
cols = 200
a = (1..20).to_a
arr = Array.new(rows) { Array.new(cols) { a.sample } }

t = Time.now
len, path = longest_increasing_path(arr)
  #=> [12, [[86, 121], [86, 120], [86, 119], [87, 119], [87, 118], [86, 118],
  #   [85, 118], [85, 117], [86, 117], [87, 117], [88, 117], [89, 117]]] 
Time.now - t
  #=> 0.153562 seconds 

path.map { |r,c| arr[r][c] }
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 19, 20]
```

**Explanation**

First let's consider the helper method `greater_neighbors` for example #1. For `arr` as shown,

```
row_indices = 0..arr.size-1
  #=> 0..2 
col_indices = 0..arr.first.size-1
  #=> 0..2
```

Next, (thinking of `arr` as a matrix) we group locations with the same value:

```
value_to_locs = row_indices.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |r,h|
  col_indices.each { |c| h[arr[r][c]] << [r,c] } }
  #=> {9=>[[0, 0], [0, 1]], 4=>[[0, 2]], 6=>[[1, 0], [1, 1]],
  #    8=>[[1, 2]], 2=>[[2, 0]], 1=>[[2, 1], [2, 2]]} 

processed = {}
```

This hash will contain the locations that have been examined.

```
low, high = value_to_locs.keys.minmax
  #=> [1, 9]
```

This provides the order by which locations with given values are processed, from `high` down to `low`.

```
enum0 = high.downto(low)
  #=> #<Enumerator: 9:downto(1)>
```

The first element of `enum0` is generated and passed to the block:

```
x = enum0.next
  #=> 9
```

and

```
value_to_locs.key?(x)
  #=> true
```

is executed, so we don't execute `next`.

We now consider all locations with the value `9`, then those with value `8`, and so on.

After the `9` is generated and passed to the block, and `next` is not executed, the following calculation is performed:

```
b = value_to_locs[x]
  #=> [[0, 0], [0, 1]] 
enum1 = b.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[0, 0], [0, 1]]:each> 
loc = enum1.next
  #=> [0, 0]
c = greater_neighbors(loc, arr, row_indices, col_indices)
  #=> []
```

The method `greater_neighbors` simply constructs an array of all locations adjacent to `loc` whose values are greater than the value at `loc`.

```
next_on_path = c.max_by { |nloc| processed[nloc][:len] }
  #=> nil
processed[loc] = next_on_path ? 
  { len: 1+processed[next_on_path][:len], next: next_on_path } :
  { len: 1, next: nil }
  #=> {:len=>1, :next=>nil}
processed
  #=> {[0, 0]=>{:len=>1, :next=>nil}}
```

We now generate the next and last element of `enum1` and pass it to the block:

```
loc = enum1.next
  #=> [0, 1]
```

The calculations for this location are similar to those for `[0, 0]`, resulting in:

```
processed
  #=> {[0, 0]=>{:len=>1, :next=>nil}, [0, 1]=>{:len=>1, :next=>nil}}
```

We have reached the last element of `enum1`, so we next perform:

```
x = enum0.next
  #=> 8
value_to_locs.key?(x)
  #=> true # so next is not executed
b = value_to_locs[x]
  #=> [[1, 2]] 
enum1 = b.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[1, 2]]:each> 
loc = enum1.next
  #=> [1, 2] 
c = greater_neighbors(loc, arr, row_indices, col_indices)
  #=> []
```

Again, there is nowhere to go from this location, so we obtain:

```
processed
  #=> {[0, 0]=>{:len=>1, :next=>nil}, [0, 1]=>{:len=>1, :next=>nil},
  #    [1, 2]=>{:len=>1, :next=>nil}}
```

Continuing,

```
x = enum0.next
  #=> 7
value_to_locs.key?(x)
  #=> false # so next is executed

x = enum0.next
  #=> 6 
value_to_locs.key?(x)
  #=> true # so next is executed
b = value_to_locs[x]
  #=> [[1, 0], [1, 1]] 
enum1 = b.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[1, 0], [1, 1]]:each> 
loc = enum1.next
  #=> [1, 0] 
c = greater_neighbors(loc, arr, row_indices, col_indices)
  #=> [[0, 0]] 
next_on_path = c.max_by { |nloc| processed[nloc][:len] }
  #=> [0, 0] 
processed[loc] = next_on_path ? 
  { len: 1+processed[next_on_path][:len], next: next_on_path } :
  { len: 1, next: nil }
  #=> {:len=>2, :next=>[0, 0]} 
processed
  #=> {[0, 0]=>{:len=>1, :next=>nil}, [0, 1]=>{:len=>1, :next=>nil},
  #    [1, 2]=>{:len=>1, :next=>nil}, [1, 0]=>{:len=>2, :next=>[0, 0]}}
```

At last, we've come to a location (`[1, 0]`) that is adjacent to a higher-valued location (`[0, 0]`).

This calculations continue in this way until we obtain:

```
processed
  #=> {[0, 0]=>{:len=>1, :next=>nil},    [0, 1]=>{:len=>1, :next=>nil},
  #    [1, 2]=>{:len=>1, :next=>nil},    [1, 0]=>{:len=>2, :next=>[0, 0]},
  #    [1, 1]=>{:len=>2, :next=>[0, 1]}, [0, 2]=>{:len=>2, :next=>[1, 2]},
  #    [2, 0]=>{:len=>3, :next=>[1, 0]}, [2, 1]=>{:len=>4, :next=>[2, 0]},
  #    [2, 2]=>{:len=>2, :next=>[1, 2]}}
```

All that remains is to find the key-value pair `k=>v` for which `v[:len]` is greatest and then extract the longest path. That is done by the helper `extract`, which, like `greater_neighbors`, is straightforward.

Comment: Brilliant solution--thanks for the insight. On a more conceptual basis--what do you think is the difference in using DFS in all 4 directions versus just passing a brute force function in that way? My question on time complexity of those algorithms isn't Java focused-- that was just example code-- I'm just trying to intuit how that runtime is derived.

Comment: I haven't read this whole post (I'm on a smartphone, sorry), but if it involves sorting the entire matrix, then it won't be O(mn), because that step alone is O(mn log mn).

Comment: Sunny, I think you're right that brute force searches would be O(`4^(mn)`). My algorithm is O(`n*m`), because each of `n*m` elements requires a number of operations that does not increase as a function of `n` and `m`.

Comment: @ruakh, the time complexity must be at least O(n*m) as every element must be examined.

Comment: Sunny, I'm not sure of the space complexity of brute-force methods.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I think you must have misunderstood my comment somehow. What I'm saying is that, in the worst case, `value_to_locs.keys.sort` is not in O(mn).

Comment: @ruakh, I see. Thanks. I'll fix it in the morning. Still, O(nm log nm ) ain't chopped liver. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: O(mn log mn) is not bad, but the fairly straightforward combination of dynamic programming and breadth-first search (out from local maxima) takes only O(mn) time.

Comment: @ruakh, I made a small change to make my method O(mn). My solution employs dynamic programming with the state variable being a lower bound on the first elements of longest increasing paths. Did you have in mind a dynamic programming approach that has the same state variable? Could you elaborate how the breadth-first search would work?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: My approach: create an m-by-n array `path_lengths` representing "length of longest increasing path that starts at this position". Find all local maxima (= elements with no greater-valued neighbors), add their locations to a processing queue. While the queue is not empty: dequeue an element, set `path_lengths[m][n]`, check its lesser-valued neighbors to see if any of them are now ready to be processed, if so add them to the processing queue. At the end, examine `path_lengths` to find the longest path.